# Composite Unique key constraint with multiple null value in one of the column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a unique key on table x with 3 column (a,b,c) where a,b,c are foreign keys and c can be null in x table.

```
a b c
- - ----
1 1    1
1 1    2
1 1 NULL
1 1 NUll
```

Above rows are valid on MySQL and inserting rows with multiple null does not violate constraint.But this is not true with Oracle , SQL-Server

what are the best practices in this scenario?

with every unique constraint unique index is getting created and if i disable unique index multiple nulls are allowed in SQL-Server also ( with filtered index)

i need to set multiple value in column c with null as its foreign key.

Please suggest should i remove the unique key constraint , should i remove foreign key from column c in table x. or we have any other solution.

Comment: A unique key which isn't and a foreign key which isn't may be allowed in mysql but is pretty pointless.

Comment: I have a application which is supported in 4 database

Comment: If your columns aren't unique then you can't have a unique constraint on them (or, at least, shouldn't have one, in the case of MySQL).

Comment: Columns are unique but when one of the column value is NULL its not unique.

Comment: Isn't that a good thing? If there's a unique constraint on (a,b,c) then adding two (1,1,null) would be wrong anyway?

Comment: No i want uniqueness check only in case of not null. Or if this is not a best practice then what should be the approach.

Answer (score 2):

This index does what you want:

```
create unique index idx_t_abc on t(
  case when c is not null then a end,
  case when c is not null then b end, 
  case when c is not null then c end);
```

Tested only in Oracle. Similar question at asktom site: [unique index with null values](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:39951226964354).

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you can use a filtered index:

```
create index unq_t_a_b_c on t(a, b, c)
    where c is not null;
```

This should also work on Postgres and Postgres-derived databases.

Oracle doesn't support filtered indexes.  You can use computed columns for this purpose -- assuming you have a primary key:

```
create index unq_t_a_b_c on t(a, b, c, (case when c is null then pk end));
```

This will allow multiple values when `c` is null.